# will paginate in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading my rails 2.3.8 app to rails 3.0.1  while using will_paginate in one module

for example:

```
 <%= will_paginate @sample , :renderer => 'RemoteLinkRenderer' , :remote => {:loading => 'loadingPanel.show()',:complete => 'loadingPanel.hide()' }  %>
```

This code isn't  working.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to look rude but "This code doesn't working" isn't enough to be helped. You should provide more informations about your problem :)

Comment: I have used will paginate in  front end part like this <%= will_paginate @sample , :renderer => 'RemoteLinkRenderer' , :remote => {:loading => 'loadingPanel.show()',:complete => 'loadingPanel.hide()' } %>, in the admin end <%= will_paginate @sample , :renderer => 'RemoteLinkRenderer' , :remote => {:update=>'sample_content',:loading => 'loadingPanel.show()',:complete => 'loadingPanel.hide()' } %> this admin end will paginate working , will paginate  using in the front end not working in the remote did update div required ? since in the front end i'm using will paginate in the partial file .

Comment: Are you sure it's a will_paginate issue? I mean, it could be another thing, maybe ajax/javascript related. I distrust a library problem that doesn't show always up. For example, Are you sure that your link fires up the ajax request correctly? I know I didn't give you a great help with my further questions but you know it's not so simple to understand a problem behind a monitor.

Answer (score 2):

You are not simply using will paginate. Apparently, you are also using [this patch](http://weblog.redlinesoftware.com/2008/1/30/willpaginate-and-remote-links), and it is not working with Rails 3. 
You should edit the question and update it's title to somthing like "remote pagination via Ajax with will_paginate and rails 3".

There is one html5-based solution described [here](http://rorramblings.blogspot.com/2010/11/willpaginate-and-ajax-in-rails-3.html)

To convert this solution into non-html5 you may maybe do something like this(*):

```
$$('.pagination a').each(function(e){
  var link=e.getAttribute('href');
  e.setAttribute(
        'onclick',
        'new Ajax.Request(\'' + link + '\', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true})');
  e.writeAttribute('href',null);
}
```

* has to be trimmed if there are multiple paginations...